# Issue implementing codepen.io mouse trail

Tags: javascript, html, css

im trying to implement this

https://codepen.io/Mertl/pen/XWdyRwJ into a hugo template https://themes.gohugo.io/somrat/ ;

I dont know where to put the html file; put only the no cursor part into style.css; and copy the .js into script.js, nothing happens on the localhost website when I do this, any help is appreciated <3

code: (html, css and js)

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

```
body,
html {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  background: rgb(30, 30, 30);
  cursor: none;
}
```

```
window.onload = function () {
  //functions definition

  //class definition
  class segm {
    constructor(x, y, l) {
      this.b = Math.random()*1.9+0.1;
      this.x0 = x;
      this.y0 = y;
      this.a = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
      this.x1 = this.x0 + l * Math.cos(this.a);
      this.y1 = this.y0 + l * Math.sin(this.a);
      this.l = l;
    }
    update(x, y) {
      this.x0 = x;
      this.y0 = y;
      this.a = Math.atan2(this.y1 - this.y0, this.x1 - this.x0);
      this.x1 = this.x0 + this.l * Math.cos(this.a);
      this.y1 = this.y0 + this.l * Math.sin(this.a);
    }
  }
  class rope {
    constructor(tx, ty, l, b, slq, typ) {
      if(typ == "l"){
        this.res = l / 2;
      }else{
        this.res = l / slq;
      }
      this.type = typ;
      this.l = l;
      this.segm = [];
      this.segm.push(new segm(tx, ty, this.l / this.res));
      for (let i = 1; i < this.res; i++) {
        this.segm.push(
          new segm(this.segm[i - 1].x1, this.segm[i - 1].y1, this.l / this.res)
        );
      }
      this.b = b;
    }
    update(t) {
      this.segm[0].update(t.x, t.y);
      for (let i = 1; i < this.res; i++) {
        this.segm[i].update(this.segm[i - 1].x1, this.segm[i - 1].y1);
      }
    }
    show() {
      if(this.type == "l"){
      c.beginPath();
      for (let i = 0; i < this.segm.length; i++) {
        c.lineTo(this.segm[i].x0, this.segm[i].y0);
      }
      c.lineTo(
        this.segm[this.segm.length - 1].x1,
        this.segm[this.segm.length - 1].y1
      );
      c.strokeStyle = "white";
      c.lineWidth = this.b;
      c.stroke();

      c.beginPath();
      c.arc(this.segm[0].x0, this.segm[0].y0, 1, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      c.fillStyle = "white";
      c.fill();

      c.beginPath();
      c.arc(
        this.segm[this.segm.length - 1].x1,
        this.segm[this.segm.length - 1].y1,
        2,
        0,
        2 * Math.PI
      );
      c.fillStyle = "white";
      c.fill();
      }else{
      for (let i = 0; i < this.segm.length; i++) {
        c.beginPath();
        c.arc(this.segm[i].x0, this.segm[i].y0, this.segm[i].b, 0, 2*Math.PI);
        c.fillStyle = "white";
      c.fill();
      }
        c.beginPath();
      c.arc(
        this.segm[this.segm.length - 1].x1,
        this.segm[this.segm.length - 1].y1,
        2, 0, 2*Math.PI
      );
      c.fillStyle = "white";
      c.fill();
      }
    }
  }

  //setting up canvas
  let c = init("canvas").c,
    canvas = init("canvas").canvas,
    w = (canvas.width = window.innerWidth),
    h = (canvas.height = window.innerHeight),
    ropes = [];

  //variables definition
  let nameOfVariable = "value",
    mouse = {},
    last_mouse = {},
    rl = 50,
    randl = [],
    target = { x: w/2, y: h/2 },
    last_target = {},
    t = 0,
    q = 10,
    da = [],
    type = "l";

  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    if(Math.random() > 0.25){
        type = "l";
      }else{
        type = "o";
      }
    ropes.push(
      new rope(
        w / 2,
        h / 2,
        (Math.random() * 1 + 0.5) * 500,
        Math.random() * 0.4 + 0.1,
        Math.random()*15+5,
        type
      )
    );
    randl.push(Math.random() * 2 - 1);
    da.push(0);
  }

  //place for objects in animation
  function draw() {
    
    if (mouse.x) {
      target.errx = mouse.x - target.x;
      target.erry = mouse.y - target.y;
    } else {
      target.errx =
        w / 2 +
        (h / 2 - q) *
          Math.sqrt(2) *
          Math.cos(t) /
          (Math.pow(Math.sin(t), 2) + 1) -
        target.x;
      target.erry =
        h / 2 +
        (h / 2 - q) *
          Math.sqrt(2) *
          Math.cos(t) *
          Math.sin(t) /
          (Math.pow(Math.sin(t), 2) + 1) -
        target.y;
    }

    target.x += target.errx / 10;
    target.y += target.erry / 10;

    t += 0.01;
    
    for (let i = 0; i < ropes.length; i++) {
      if (randl[i] > 0) {
        da[i] += (1 - randl[i]) / 10;
      } else {
        da[i] += (-1 - randl[i]) / 10;
      }
      ropes[i].update({
        x:
          target.x +
          randl[i] * rl * Math.cos((i * 2 * Math.PI) / ropes.length + da[i]),
        y:
          target.y +
          randl[i] * rl * Math.sin((i * 2 * Math.PI) / ropes.length + da[i])
      });
      ropes[i].show();
    }
    last_target.x = target.x;
    last_target.y = target.y;
  }

  //mouse position
  canvas.addEventListener(
    "mousemove",
    function (e) {
      last_mouse.x = mouse.x;
      last_mouse.y = mouse.y;

      mouse.x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
      mouse.y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    },
    false
  );
  
  canvas.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(e) {
    mouse.x = false;
    mouse.y = false;
  });

  //animation frame
  function loop() {
    window.requestAnimFrame(loop);
    c.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    draw();
  }

  //window resize
  window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
    (w = canvas.width = window.innerWidth),
      (h = canvas.height = window.innerHeight);
    loop();
  });

  //animation runner
  loop();
  setInterval(loop, 1000 / 60);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to implement like this

```js
window.init = function(elemid) {
  let canvas = document.getElementById(elemid),
    c = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    w = (canvas.width = window.innerWidth),
    h = (canvas.height = window.innerHeight);
  c.fillStyle = "rgba(30,30,30,1)";
  c.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
  return {c:c,canvas:canvas};
}

window.requestAnimFrame = function() {
  return (
    window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback) {
      window.setTimeout(callback);
    }
  );
};

window.spaceworm = function () {
  //functions definition

  //class definition
  class segm {
    constructor(x, y, l) {
      this.b = Math.random()*1.9+0.1;
      this.x0 = x;
      this.y0 = y;
      this.a = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
      this.x1 = this.x0 + l * Math.cos(this.a);
      this.y1 = this.y0 + l * Math.sin(this.a);
      this.l = l;
    }
    update(x, y) {
      this.x0 = x;
      this.y0 = y;
      this.a = Math.atan2(this.y1 - this.y0, this.x1 - this.x0);
      this.x1 = this.x0 + this.l * Math.cos(this.a);
      this.y1 = this.y0 + this.l * Math.sin(this.a);
    }
  }
  class rope {
    constructor(tx, ty, l, b, slq, typ) {
      if(typ == "l"){
        this.res = l / 2;
      }else{
        this.res = l / slq;
      }
      this.type = typ;
      this.l = l;
      this.segm = [];
      this.segm.push(new segm(tx, ty, this.l / this.res));
      for (let i = 1; i < this.res; i++) {
        this.segm.push(
          new segm(this.segm[i - 1].x1, this.segm[i - 1].y1, this.l / this.res)
        );
      }
      this.b = b;
    }
    update(t) {
      this.segm[0].update(t.x, t.y);
      for (let i = 1; i < this.res; i++) {
        this.segm[i].update(this.segm[i - 1].x1, this.segm[i - 1].y1);
      }
    }
    show() {
      if(this.type == "l"){
      c.beginPath();
      for (let i = 0; i < this.segm.length; i++) {
        c.lineTo(this.segm[i].x0, this.segm[i].y0);
      }
      c.lineTo(
        this.segm[this.segm.length - 1].x1,
        this.segm[this.segm.length - 1].y1
      );
      c.strokeStyle = "white";
      c.lineWidth = this.b;
      c.stroke();

      c.beginPath();
      c.arc(this.segm[0].x0, this.segm[0].y0, 1, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      c.fillStyle = "white";
      c.fill();

      c.beginPath();
      c.arc(
        this.segm[this.segm.length - 1].x1,
        this.segm[this.segm.length - 1].y1,
        2,
        0,
        2 * Math.PI
      );
      c.fillStyle = "white";
      c.fill();
      }else{
      for (let i = 0; i < this.segm.length; i++) {
        c.beginPath();
        c.arc(this.segm[i].x0, this.segm[i].y0, this.segm[i].b, 0, 2*Math.PI);
        c.fillStyle = "white";
      c.fill();
      }
        c.beginPath();
      c.arc(
        this.segm[this.segm.length - 1].x1,
        this.segm[this.segm.length - 1].y1,
        2, 0, 2*Math.PI
      );
      c.fillStyle = "white";
      c.fill();
      }
    }
  }

  //setting up canvas
  let c = init("canvas").c,
    canvas = init("canvas").canvas,
    w = (canvas.width = window.innerWidth),
    h = (canvas.height = window.innerHeight),
    ropes = [];

  //variables definition
  let nameOfVariable = "value",
    mouse = {},
    last_mouse = {},
    rl = 50,
    randl = [],
    target = { x: w/2, y: h/2 },
    last_target = {},
    t = 0,
    q = 10,
    da = [],
    type = "l";

  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    if(Math.random() > 0.25){
        type = "l";
      }else{
        type = "o";
      }
    ropes.push(
      new rope(
        w / 2,
        h / 2,
        (Math.random() * 1 + 0.5) * 500,
        Math.random() * 0.4 + 0.1,
        Math.random()*15+5,
        type
      )
    );
    randl.push(Math.random() * 2 - 1);
    da.push(0);
  }

  //place for objects in animation
  function draw() {
    
    if (mouse.x) {
      target.errx = mouse.x - target.x;
      target.erry = mouse.y - target.y;
    } else {
      target.errx =
        w / 2 +
        (h / 2 - q) *
          Math.sqrt(2) *
          Math.cos(t) /
          (Math.pow(Math.sin(t), 2) + 1) -
        target.x;
      target.erry =
        h / 2 +
        (h / 2 - q) *
          Math.sqrt(2) *
          Math.cos(t) *
          Math.sin(t) /
          (Math.pow(Math.sin(t), 2) + 1) -
        target.y;
    }

    target.x += target.errx / 10;
    target.y += target.erry / 10;

    t += 0.01;
    
    for (let i = 0; i < ropes.length; i++) {
      if (randl[i] > 0) {
        da[i] += (1 - randl[i]) / 10;
      } else {
        da[i] += (-1 - randl[i]) / 10;
      }
      ropes[i].update({
        x:
          target.x +
          randl[i] * rl * Math.cos((i * 2 * Math.PI) / ropes.length + da[i]),
        y:
          target.y +
          randl[i] * rl * Math.sin((i * 2 * Math.PI) / ropes.length + da[i])
      });
      ropes[i].show();
    }
    last_target.x = target.x;
    last_target.y = target.y;
  }

  //mouse position
  canvas.addEventListener(
    "mousemove",
    function (e) {
      last_mouse.x = mouse.x;
      last_mouse.y = mouse.y;

      mouse.x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
      mouse.y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    },
    false
  );
  
  canvas.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(e) {
    mouse.x = false;
    mouse.y = false;
  });

  //animation frame
  function loop() {
    window.requestAnimFrame(loop);
    c.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    draw();
  }

  //window resize
  window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
    (w = canvas.width = window.innerWidth),
      (h = canvas.height = window.innerHeight);
    loop();
  });

  //animation runner
  loop();
  setInterval(loop, 1000 / 60);
};

window.onload = spaceworm;
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  background: rgb(30, 30, 30);
  cursor: none;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

---

---

---

---

Comment: Also you can insert as a carousel slider item on your theme.

<div class="slider"><canvas id="canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></canvas></div>